# I want to write birth date to an excel file using php

Tags: preg-match-all

I used:

```
preg_match_all('/\<tr\>\s*\<td\>Birthdate:\<\/td\>\s*\<td class="padleft"\>(.*?)\<\/td\>\s*\<\/tr\>/ism', $p, $birth);
```

In excel I'm getting output as `13&#39;th May, 195`. How do I remove `&#39` from it?

The excel should take `&#39` as `'`.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's built-in function [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to remove the HTML formatting.  Here is an example:

```
$p = '
    <tr>
      <td>Birthdate:</td>
      <td class="padleft">13&#039;th May, 1955</td>
    </tr>';

preg_match('~Birthdate:</td>\s*<td class="padleft">(.*?)</td>~ism', $p, $birth);
$birth = html_entity_decode($birth[1], ENT_QUOTES);
print $birth;
```

This returns:

```
13'th May, 1955
```

---

*Note: As a tip, you don't have to escape the `<` and `>` symbols in your regular expression.  You will have to escape the `/`, however since it is the delimiter you are using.  You can use a different delimiter instead so you don't have to escape those as well.  In the example above, I used the `~` as the delimiter so nothing has to be escaped.*